# Hybrid Merge/Insertion sort algorithm

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

Explanation: Although merge sort runs in Ω(nlgn) and insertion sort runs in Ω(n^2), the constant factors in insertion sort can make it faster in implementation for small problem sizes.  This sorting implementation should still be stable.

Recursive Merge sort subroutine method:

```
private static void recursiveMergeSort(double[] arr, int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    if (lowerBound < upperBound) {
        // Split the sub array into halves
        int mid = lowerBound + (upperBound - lowerBound) / 2;
        recursiveMergeSort(arr, lowerBound, mid);
        recursiveMergeSort(arr, mid + 1, upperBound);
        merge(arr, lowerBound, mid, upperBound);
    }
}
```

Merge method: *note-
I would like to replace the while loop with for and if-else statements.

```
private static void merge(double[] arr, int left, int mid, int right) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = left;
    //System.out.println("used merge");

    // Sizes of the temporary arrays to be copied
    int n1 = (mid - left) + 1;
    int n2 = (right - mid);

    // Create temporary arrays and copy data
    double[] leftTemp = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, left, mid + 1);
    double[] rightTemp = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, mid + 1, right + 1);

    // Merge the temp arrays back into arr[left...right]
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (leftTemp[i] <= rightTemp[j]) {
            arr[k++] = leftTemp[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = rightTemp[j++];
        }
    }

    // Copy remaining elements, if any
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k++] = leftTemp[i++];
    }
    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k++] = rightTemp[j++];
    }
}
```

Insertion sort subroutine method:

```
private static void insertionSort(double[] arr, int left, int right){
    for (int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
        double key = arr[i];
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= left && arr[j] > key) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

Hybrid merge/insertion sorting method:

Optimized is a value that is best set between [25,100]

```
private static void insertionRecursiveMergeSort(double[] arr, int left, int right) {
    // If <= OPTIMIZED use insertion sort subroutine
    if (right <= left + OPTIMIZED - 1) {
        insertionSort(arr, left, right);
    } else {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        insertionRecursiveMergeSort(arr, left, mid);
        insertionRecursiveMergeSort(arr, mid + 1, right);
        merge(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
}
```

For test runs, I used array sizes 1M, 2M, 3M, and 5M with optimized set to 25, 50, 100, and 125.

Answer (score 3):

Optimization notes.

- Allocate the temporary array once, and pass it down to the recursive invocations.
- <strike>Do not fall back to the insertion sort immediately. Postpone it until all the recursions complete, and insertion sort the entire array once.</strike>

  It feels scary to insertion sort the entire array. Wouldn't it degrade performance to \$O(n^2)\$? The answer is no. The array is already "almost sorted": every element is at most `OPTIMIZED` away from its final destination. Therefore, an inner loop does at most `OPTIMIZED` iterations per element, and the overall complexity is \$O(n * \texttt{OPTIMIZED})\$. This observation also hints that `OPTIMIZED` should be in a ballpark of \$\log n\$.

  **Edit**: I don't know what I was thinking. The above is totally wrong (it is valid for quicksort, but not here), except the observation that `OPTIMIZED` should be in a ballpark of \$\log n\$.
- A little-known trick allows to cut the number of comparisons in the insertion sort in half. Instead of

  ```
    while (j >= left && arr[j] > key)
  ```

  consider first comparing `key` to `arr[left]`:

  ```
    if (key < arr[left]) {
        // The key shall land at the left. No need to compare values anymore
        for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j-1];
        }
    } else {
        // arr[left] is a natural sentinel. No need to compare indices anymore
        for (j = i; arr[j] > key; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j-1];
        }
    }
  ```

  Now if you opt for a postponed insertion sort, it could be optimized even more: find the min among first `OPTIMIZED` elements and swap it with `arr[0]`. Now there is no need to test for `key < arr[left]` - it is guaranteed to fail. Go straight into the unguarded loop.